# Arrows in TikZ tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I've been trying to create a tree consisting out of parents and nodes connected with arrows. I have created almost what I had in mind, except from that the arrows point the wrong direction.

could anyone be of help here?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ 
label distance=3mm,
every label/.style={blue},
event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,text width=3cm,text centered,anchor=north},
edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70,-latex},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-0.50cm)-| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=1cm,growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
]
\node [event] {result}
    child {node {cause1}}
    child {node {cause2}}
    child {node {cause3}
        child{ node {subcause31}}
        child{ node {subcause32}}
        child{ node {subcause33}}
        };\end{tikzpicture}]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `-latex` in `edge from parent` style with `latex-`.